# Office 365 API: Error calling Delete Event

Tags: office365

Getting an internal server error (500) when making a rest call to delete an event.

```
Request:
DELETE /api/v1.0/Users('user1@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com')/Events/AAMkADZlN2MxYmJhLWUzMGUtNGY3Zi05YzBjLTdhNTExMzc3NmY4YgBGAAAAAABuvuSdIZ-9TLUADSOLnckDBwAYbp8b1lFySrerP-06-Cx4AAAAAAENAAAYbp8b1lFySrerP-06-Cx4AAACVeUmAAA= HTTP/1.1
Host: outlook.office365.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjFAbXljb21wYW55Lm9ubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbTpwYXNzd29yZA==
Cache-Control: no-cache

Request URL: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('user1@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com')/Events/AAMkADZlN2MxYmJhLWUzMGUtNGY3Zi05YzBjLTdhNTExMzc3NmY4YgBGAAAAAABuvuSdIZ-9TLUADSOLnckDBwAYbp8b1lFySrerP-06-Cx4AAAAAAENAAAYbp8b1lFySrerP-06-Cx4AAACVeUmAAA=
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    }
}
```

GET and PATCH both work.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft: "It's interesting you can get GET and PATCH to work using Basic authentication in a delegate scenario". All the methods except delete (by other user) still work including create. I think this is a Microsoft bug that no developer wants to sit an fix. All other responses come back with some form of explanation as to why you can't delete, but in this case its an "Internal Server Error" which tells me that something bad happened server side.

I have tried the client credential route but it turns out you have to build a x.509 certificate and many other steps need to be taken which are not mentioned in the REST API. This might help getting the client credentials working as  a daemon. https://gist.github.com/NGMarmaduke/a088943edbe4e703129d

Answer (score 0):

That should work if you authenticate as the mailbox owner. However, delegate access (accessing User1's mailbox as User2) isn't supported by the REST APIs currently. It's interesting you can get GET and PATCH to work using Basic authentication in a delegate scenario. However, I should warn that Basic auth for the REST APIs will be discontinued in the future. The supported way of using these API's is via an OAuth token.

What is your end goal? Is delegate access a key component to your solution, or do you just need for your app to be able to act on user's calendars?

Comment: Hmm. Are you authenticating as the same user you're specifying in the URL?

Comment: Yes, I am. Calling GET and PATCH for the same event id works. I also tried calling DELETE for an event that no longer exists and got back ErrorItemNotFound which tells me that I must be getting past that point when I use an existing event id. Whatever the issue is, O365 API implementation should not be throwing NullReferenceExceptions. Does DELETE work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. It definitely sounds like something unexpected is happening. Can you instrument your requests with User-Agent, client-request-id, and return-client-request-id headers (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn720380(v=exchg.150).aspx) then record the request-id from the response and post those values? I'd like to see what we can track down from the server side.

Comment: I was wrong in my previous comment. It works for the same user but breaks when authenticated as a user with Editor permissions on the calendar. The request-id is e77f6803-7309-458d-b8bc-35245f94dfbf. Thanks.

Comment: Currently in production, our application reads other user's calendars without knowing their passwords. The new feature we are adding is to add, update, and delete calendar events. Adding and updating works but ran into this problem with delete.

Comment: If your app has user interaction at all, then you can definitely do the OAuth2 authorization code grant flow and still not know the user's password. If it doesn't have user interaction, then you'll want to check out the client credential flow, which we'll be releasing support for soon. That allows your admin to grant consent for the app to access any mailbox in the organization.